# Provide wsdl url and get all the requests in that wsdl url

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui, soap-client

Is there a way in Java, If I provide the wsdl url, I can get all the requests that is available in that service?

Here is a sample service. http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL.
Please help.

It looks like there is a way to do this - Please [see](http://pritikaur23.wordpress.com/2013/06/16/saving-a-soapui-project-and-sending-requests-using-soapui-api/).
Not able to find maven dependency or jar for it.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

You can use wsdlimport and it will build you a soap client. This would be the way I would do it. The @WebClient class that is generated will list all the possible operations you can call.

See this link
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

Otherwise you would have to parse the wsdl file looking for bindings along with their name.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. wsimport will give me the sources. I dont want the sources. I just want to list the requests available in that wsdl.

Comment: If you want to parse the wsdl xml, you should probably just use xpath to fetch the <wsdl:operation name="ValidateZip"> and get the name of the operation. That will be your "requests" that are available.

Comment: Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349358/during-the-search-xpath-returns-null for grabbing the operation name.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a better way to do this than the one you have stated above? I am just curious - No offense!!

Comment: IMHO that is your best option, either creating the client and using reflection to get the operation names or doing xpath to get the operation names directly from the wsdl.